# Individual Labels for different languages in apex 4.11

Tags: oracle-apex

for example I have a textfield and I want to show the labelname in different languages. I create a text message with the key "label_password" for english and german.

How can I configure the the textfield to use the text message "label_password"?

I found nothing in the web.

Bye,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer, but I have a problem with point 3.

First I make a label field ("P201_LABEL") with the source "APEX_LANG.MESSAGE('LABEL_PASSWORD', V('APP_USER'));". And it works fine. Then I change the type to hidden item. Last step is to configure a text field, but what is the value in the field "Label"? When I put in "&P201_LABEL." the label is empty.

Where is the problem?

Thanks for help,
Christian

Comment: oh I found the error. The Hidden Item was set at the end. For this reason the label was blank.

Comment: You must use comments to provide feedback in an effective way, in this case you have used a new answer and i have not been notified. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Text Messages in oracle apex are intended for translating application messages. For example, you could define the message GREETING_MSG in English as:

> Good morning %0

Or, you could define the message GREETING_MSG in German as:

> Guten Tag %0

And not for items labels at all, this task is best done by using **Translate Application** option in Globalization section.

But, if you want to use Apex Messages to set label caption, you must use LANG.MESSAGE api as described in apex documentation [Apex 4.1 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc.41/e21676/apex_lang.htm#AEAPI1156).

Since it is PL/SQL function you have to:

1. create a Hidden Item (Sample : `&P101_HIDDEN_VALUE.`) and set source type to **PL/SQL Expression**
2. Enter `APEX_LANG.MESSAGE('LABEL_PASSWORD', V('APP_USER'));`
3. Use hidden item as substition in label of normal item. Sample `&P101_HIDDEN_VALUE.`

See working Demo here : [Multi Language Label App](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=117407:101:0::NO::P101_LANGUAGE:de)
Source Code App: [multi-language-app.sql](https://github.com/ftaveras/colapex)